# [expr.call]/1 seems to miss one possible outcome when a function call returns a function pointer type. Am I correct on this?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[expr.call]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#expr.call-1):

> A function call is a postfix expression followed by parentheses
> containing a possibly empty, comma-separated list of
> *initializer-clauses* which constitute the arguments to the function.
>
> [Note 1: If the postfix expression is a function or member function
> name, the appropriate function and the validity of the call are
> determined according to the rules in [over.match]. — end note]
>
> The postfix expression shall have function type or function pointer
> type. For a call to a non-member function or to a static member
> function, the postfix expression shall either be an **lvalue** that
> refers to a function (in which case the function-to-pointer standard
> conversion ([conv.func]) is suppressed on the postfix expression), or
> have function pointer type.

My interpretation of this clause is that the lvalue highlighted above is valid for both, an id-expression referring to a function or to a function pointer type. But let's assume that I'm wrong, i.e., that a function pointer type could be a prvalue. However, as [expr.call]/1 is mute about this, one could argue that [basic.lval]/7, see below, would apply, i.e., the prvalue would have to be converted to an xvalue. But that doesn't seem to happen, as we observe the disassembly generated by the compilers.

[[basic.lval]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#7)

> Whenever a prvalue appears as an operand of an operator that expects a
> glvalue for that operand, the temporary materialization conversion is
> applied to convert the expression to an xvalue.

[C++ Snippet](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a398e22f34d24f63):

```
#include<iostream>
void f(int a) {
    std::cout << "f(" << a << ")\n";
}
// g is a function of () returning a pointer to a function of (int) returning void

void(*g())(int) {
    return f;       // f is function of (int) returning void.
}
int main()
{
   g()(1);  // The expression `g()` is a prvalue with function-pointer type. The return of the function call `g()`
            // recursively calls function `f(1)`, which then prints `f(1)` on the output window. The recursive call
            // to the function `f` is guaranteed by the recursive definition of a postfix-expression in
            // (http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#general-1)
}
```

Disassembly by VS2019 for the expression `g()(1);` above in `main`:

```
00312562 8B F4                mov         esi,esp  
00312564 6A 01                push        1  
00312566 E8 C9 ED FF FF       call        g (0311334h)  
0031256B FF D0                call        eax  
0031256D 83 C4 04             add         esp,4
```

The disassembly for `gcc` and `clang` are very similar to the one above as can be seen [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b1dMh1). As far as I can tell, there is no conversion from the prvalue `g()` to an xvalue in the disassemblies obtained by those three compilers.

Therefore, I have to conclude that [expr.call]/1 misses something like the words highlighted below, to explain the behavior shown by the compilers.

> The postfix expression shall have function type or function pointer
> type. For a call to a non-member function or to a static member
> function, the postfix expression shall either be an lvalue that
> refers to a function (in which case the function-to-pointer standard
> conversion ([conv.func]) is suppressed on the postfix expression), or
> have function pointer type, **which in this case, will be an lvalue or a prvalue**.

With this change in [expr.call]/1, there would be no requirement for the conversion of the prvalue `g()` into an xvalue, as stated in [basic.lval]/7, simply because [expr.call]/1 is explicitly saying that a prvalue function pointer type is allowed.

Comment: "*... or have function pointer type*" seems to cover whatever value-category the postfix expression might have. What's the benefit to enumerating all the value-categories explicitly?

Comment: The sentence seems clear: the postfix expression shall either be an lvalue..., or have function pointer type. If you take door #2, there's no mention of any particular value category. In any case, things like lvalue-to-rvalue conversion are mostly conceptual; there's no "convert lvalue to rvalue" machine instruction, it's unclear what you expect to see in the generated assembly.

Comment: in general you cannot infer rules of c++ from assembly. Compilers translate your code to something that has observable behavior as if the rules layed out in the standard were followed precisely. If there is no observable difference the compilers can produce any assembly they like

Comment: @IgorTandetnik " it's unclear what you expect to see in the generated assembly" I was expecting to see something like the function `get_pf()` [here](https://godbolt.org/z/o8qeoh).

Comment: You seem to confuse outcome with requirement/expectation. [expr.call]/1 is not the paragraph which defines the value category of function call when the function returns pointer to function. It is defined in [expr.call]/14. What [expr.call]/1 doesn't say is that it expects a prvalue of function pointer type. Which is [CWG1642](http://wg21.link/cwg1642).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer "What [expr.call]/1 doesn't say is that it expects a prvalue of function pointer type." Well, that's exactly what I said in my last paragraph above. That is, if [expr.call]/1 explicitçy says that a function pointer type can be a prvalue, the alluded contradiction with [basic.lval]/7 disappears, for the compiler will not be required in this case, to convert the prvalue into an xvalue.

Comment: I just don't understand why currently prvalue should be converted to xvalue.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Now I understand what you getting at. [basic.lval]/7 simply doesn't apply in this case. Thanks a lot for the input. But I would insist that [expr.call]/1 should explicitly say that a function pointer type can be a prvalue.

Comment: _But I would insist that [expr.call]/1 should explicitly say that a function pointer type can be a prvalue_ `s/can/shall/`

Comment: As a non-native English speaker, I don't have the full command of the language. But in this case I would prefer the term `can`, as a function pointer type can also be an lvalue.

Comment: In which case, lvalue-to-rvalue conversion need be applied to read the pointer value. That's why it shall say «shall» and then http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#6 will apply.